# How can a variable typed as an enum take a value that is out of range of its elements?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, default-value

Can anyone explain to me how an a member of this enum takes a value of `0`?

```
public enum EnumLogicalOperator
{
    And = 1,
    Or = 2
}
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about C# - could it be that the enum value is null?

Comment: @Matt Ball: No, it's not nullable. And even thought, the value which it has been got is `0` not `null` !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you use `default(EnumLogicalOperator)` or `new EnumLogicalOperator()` you'll get a zero value. In other words, the *default* value of an enum type member is always 0. All enums will have the value 0 until you set them to something else.

Comment: Great, thanks. Actually I haven't thought that it's a default value. I was focusing on "How did it take a value form out of its values"

Comment: @Jack: Usual best practice is to have the default value (0) be Undefined, NotSet, Unknown, etc.  Don't forget, enums aren't limited to the defined values.  `(EnumLogicalOperator)5` is valid.

Answer (score 4):

An instance of an enum type can be created from  *any* legal value of its underlying type, even if no 'named' member of the enumeration is associated with that underlying value. In particular, it's common to see the value `0` because:

1. It is the default value of enumeration types.
2. For convenience, C# lets you implicitly convert the literal `0` to  any enumeration type.

Answer (score 4):

The default value of an enum is 0; I believe the [standard recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058.aspx) is that you always include something assigned to 0 inside your enum to account for this ("Unknown" or "None" both work well in my experience).

Answer (score 4):

It's mentioned on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> The default value of an enum E is the value produced by the expression (E)0

So basically, the default value will *always* be the integer value 0.  So I would guess that what you've got here is that LogicalOperatorWithPreviousRule has never been assigned a value.

Answer (score 3):

The *default* value of an integer variable is 0. And because the default underlying type of every enumeration element is `int`, which represents an integer, the default value of your variable will be 0.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) makes this explicit:

> The default value of an enum E is the value produced by the expression (E)0.

The only way to get a different default value is to explicitly initialize it when you declare the variable:

```
EnumLogicalOperator x = EnumLogicalOperator.Or;
```

This is why [it's generally recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058.aspx) that 0 correspond to a valid element in your enumeration, because this will be the default value of all variables of that type.

In addition, it is possible to assign *any* arbitrary integer value to a variable typed as an enum. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) warns:

> It is possible to assign any arbitrary integer value to meetingDay. For example, this line of code does not produce an error: meetingDay = (Days) 42. However, you should not do this because the implicit expectation is that an enum variable will only hold one of the values defined by the enum. To assign an arbitrary value to a variable of an enumeration type is to introduce a high risk for errors.

And this is made even clearer by the C# Language Specification (specifically, section 1.10 on enums):

> The set of values that an enum type can take on is not limited by its enum members. In particular, any value of the underlying type of an enum can be cast to the enum type and is a distinct valid value of that enum type.

This is why it's very important that public framework methods always verify that the value specified is within the range of valid values for that enumeration. You can't rely on the type checking system to ensure this for you. The Framework Design Guidelines recommend:

> Do argument validation. Do not assume enum arguments will be in the defined range. It is legal to cast any integer value into an enum even if the value is not defined in the enum.

Answer (score 3):

From the [C# Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E) (section *1.10, Enums*):

> The set of values that an enum type
>   can take on is not limited by its enum
>   members. In particular, any value of
>   the underlying type of an enum can be
>   cast to the enum type and is a
>   distinct valid value of that enum
>   type.

Also, section *4.1.2, Default constructors* specifies that enums default to `0`.

Download the document, it contains lots of interesting information :-)

Answer (score 3):

An enum can have *any* value based on its underlying type (Int32 in your case).

```
EnumLogicalOperator op = (EnumLogicalOperator) 0;
EnumLogicalOperator op = (EnumLogicalOperator) 100;
EnumLogicalOperator op = (EnumLogicalOperator) 900000;
EnumLogicalOperator op = (EnumLogicalOperator) -1;

private EnumLogicalOperator _op; // As a class member, will default to 0
```

Be sure to use [Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) when validating your input and handle error conditions. Also generally a good idea to include 0 as the value for one of your enum values.

Comment: Be careful with using `Enum.IsDefined`. Brad Abrams explains why this could potentially cause problems: [The danger of over simplification: Enum.IsDefined()](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/11/29/50903.aspx).

Comment: Right, that problem is when you are not the one who defines the enum, then assumes you will forever know the values. In this case, looks like he both defines the enum *and* is going to operate on all the values. Also ignoring the reflection issue as premature optimization.

Comment: It's applicable even if you *are* the one who defines the enum. A new value can still be added in a later version, potentially disrupting your code. Beyond that, it is implemented with reflection, so it can be a pretty expensive check if you perform it frequently or on properties that are presumed to be light calls. Anyway, I wasn't saying it was for sure a problem with the code in question; it's just a caveat to keep in mind when making a blanket recommendation to use `Enum.IsDefined`.

Comment: My point being that by adding an enum value that you yourself have to deal with, you have already disrupted your code and would be going through everywhere to fix/update anyway. The versioning issues tend to happen when you didn't know about the change. Could happen by a poor coworker perhaps, but I still wouldn't consider it an issue beyond what you've already done.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you include a member "Undefined" with value 0 or make your "And" or "Or" the 0-value.